# Fixing subdivision+crease troubles

Tags: subdivision-surface

How to fix that? I've tried to use crease, but it didn't work. Using bevel doesn't help too, but i've checked the normals orientation and it is absolutely ok!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a lot about creases but it looks like it doesn't give a good result with this kind of topology, but here are other ways to do what you want:

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with me? Bevel does not work like in solution #2. https://imgur.com/a/88QiBxv

Comment: are you talking about the parallelepiped bottom edges? it looks like you haven't given them any weight. Select all the edges on the bottom of the parallelepiped, go in the right (N) panel > Transform menu > Bevel Weight and give some weight. Actually on my picture you can't see the blue lines but I gave weight to these edges and it's hidden by the curve

Comment: if i do this, the problem appears too... https://imgur.com/a/jAPxmrp feel so dumb >_<

Comment: could you please share the object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ok with my method it looks like there are still problems underneath, so you should follow the Robin Betts advice, which is to add creases or weight (depending on the method you've chosen) on the diagonal or orthogonal vertices that are on the ground

Comment: that doesn't f*ckin work too! xD

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5418" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5418/) the model

Comment: it's ok, my bus is not finished, but the holes for taillights must be here. I can disconnect the holes to have better result, but your help was really useful and cool! Thanks a lot)

Comment: edit: I don’t see anyway to easily fix your problem, if you add some edge loops through your parallelepiped, horizontally and vertically, the result will be good, but then what's the use of crease, or bevel modifier which are supposed to save edge loops? Maybe someone has the good answer, but also maybe try to avoid this kind of tools even though I know bevel modifier can be very useful for some hard surface works. Plus, logically, your bus should be made of different objects and not one, it would simplify your work. I’m going to continue to dig the problem.

Comment: It is planned to be completed with multiple objects, but I think the body must be solid to bake normals perfectly

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can deduce, Blender is just about following [Pixar's creasing rules](http://xrt.wikidot.com/blog:31), so there's one more to add to moonboots' magnificent collection:

[image]

keep your original topology, but crease the diagonals as well.